# Play!framework2: how to match all controllers and actions in router?

Tags: playframework

In playframework 1.x we can match all controllers and actions like this:

```
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
*       /admin/{controller}/{action}            admin.{controller}.{action}
```

Is there any way to do this in 2.x ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

You can do it yourself, i.e. using [Dynamic parts spanning several /](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaRouting) + reflections, anyway I'd suggest to go with common approach for your app safety.